# Details about signed Windows driver

Tags: driver, wdk

I have custom Windows driver which is used until now without signature. I want to sign it to avoid warning messages while installing on Windows 7 and allow installation on Windows 10 without need to disable some options. Currently I test with self signed certificate and the plan is to buy real certificate when tests are finished. There are 3 questions:

1) My first test is on Windows XP (VM). XP said that driver is signed at the beginning of installation but later was displayed a message "The software... has not passed Windows Logo testing to verify its compatibility...". The same message was displayed before with unsigned driver. Is it necessary to do something else for "Windows Logo testing" or it depends on type of certificate? Can it be installed on Windows 10 without such Windows logo testing?

2) The driver signature is made on .CAT file and by this way all files are identified. Is it necessary to sign the .DLL-s separately?

3) My current WDK is old version and `Inf2cat` tool does not have `/os` option for Windows 10 (`10_X64`). If the signature is for Windows 7 (`/os:7_X64`), can it be installed on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Which is your driver, kernel mode or user mode?

I don't know about user mode drivers well, so I answer about kernel mode drivers.

1) 
If you want to install kernel mode driver on Windows10, it should be signed by Microsoft.
See also:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2016/07/26/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10-version-1607/

2) 
No. You only need to sign .CAT file.

3)
You can install driver which have signature for Windows 7, if it has Attestation Signing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/attestation-signing-a-kernel-driver-for-public-release

Comment: I think kernel mode drivers are `.sys` files. My driver contains only 2 `DLL` files - I think it is not kernel driver.

Comment: @i486 Thanks, I think your driver is user mode driver too. Please forget this answer.

Comment: Does it mean that I can use signature for Windows 7 on Windows 10 (for user mode driver)? It is printer driver btw.

Comment: @i486 Tbh, I've never signed user mode driver. I think you can use signature for Windows 7 on Windows 10, because `/os` option configures to verify that INF file complies with the signing requirements for the Windows versions that are specified by _WindowsVersionList_. - [Inf2Cat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/inf2cat)   General syntax rules for INF file does not change on Windows 10.

Comment: General syntax rules for INF file are not changed on Windows 10, I meant. You can use same INF file on Windows 7 and on Windows 10.